# Australians flying to Cuba from the USA

Tags: air-travel, usa, australian-citizens, cuba

I am an Australian flying in to LAX and wish to fly on to Cuba. What is the best way?
My wife will be in Kentucky. How would she meet up with me in Cuba?
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! As per our [help], asking subjective questions like 'what is the best way?' would be often put on hold. Could you perhaps clarify - do you mean cheapest (remember, we're not travel agents), shortest, safest, etc?  The more detail you can provide would help. Is your wife Australian too? If not, what's her citizenship?

Comment: [Here](https://www.yellowpages.com/miami-fl/agencias-de-viajes-para-cuba-5200sw-8str) you can find some agencies that would help you to find a round trip from Miami-Havana for no more than 500 dollars, the flight is about 45min, personally I use [Va Cuba](http://www.vacuba.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can fly via Mexico City, a simple [momondo search](http://www.momondo.com/flightsearch/?Search=true&TripType=1&SegNo=1&SO0=LAX&SD0=HAV&SDP0=25-02-2015&AD=1&TK=ECO&DO=false&NA=false) shows that you can buy one way tickets for 385 USD or [return tickets](http://www.momondo.com/flightsearch/?Search=true&TripType=2&SegNo=2&SO0=LAX&SD0=HAV&SDP0=24-02-2015&SO1=HAV&SD1=LAX&SDP1=04-03-2015&AD=1&TK=ECO&DO=false&NA=false) for 611 USD on some random dates that I tried, take your time and find the most suitable connections for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There still are no direct flights from the USA to Cuba.  While diplomatic relations on an upswing, US carriers still don't serve the island.  You would have to route yourselves via Mexico, Panama, Grand Caymans, Bahamas, etc.

As you are coming via the west coast and she is coming from the east, it would be less flying if she went via a Caribbean nation and you went via Mexico, then try to coordinate flight times to arrive in Havana close to the same time.

If you want to enter Cuba as a couple, then it might be most economical for her to come to you, meeting in Mexico City, as there are often pretty good vacation fares to Mexico from various US gateways.

Comment: And to you too Tom. Thanks a million. Most appreciated

Comment: [Here](https://www.yellowpages.com/miami-fl/agencias-de-viajes-para-cuba-5200sw-8str) you can find some agencies that would help you to find a round trip from Miami-Havana for no more than 500 dollars, the flight is about 45min, personally I use [Va Cuba](http://www.vacuba.com/)